# jquery animation in menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to create a menu bar using jquery. I am using the following code,

```
<div class="menu">
<table align="center">

<tr>
<td class="menu_item" style="background:green;" >
<a style="color: white;" href="index.php?view=Index">Home</a>
</td>
<td class="menu_item" style="background:blue;" >
<a style="color: white;" href="index.php?view=Services"> Service </a>
</td>
<td class="menu_item" style="background:red;" >
<a style="color: white;" href="index.php?view=About"> About </a>
</td>
<td class="menu_item" style="background:yellow;" >
<a style="color: white;" href="index.php?view=Download"> Download</a>
</td>
<td class="menu_item" style="background:pink;" >
<a style="color: white;" href="index.php?view=Contact"> Contact</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<hr>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
     //When mouse rolls over  
     $(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){ 

         $(this).slideUp(1000, method, callback});

     //When mouse is removed  
     $(".menu_item").mouseout(function(){  
         $(this).slideUp(1000, method, callback});

 });
</script>
```

The mouseover and mouse out functions are working, i checked those using alert boxes but no change is happening to the items...? where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have a few syntax errors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
     //When mouse rolls over  
     $(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){ 
         $(this).slideUp(1000);
     });

     //When mouse is removed  
     $(".menu_item").mouseout(function(){  
         $(this).slideUp(1000);
     });
});
```

I'm not sure, however, what you're trying to achieve here. I.e., the above [*works*](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/hqFBM/) but I'm not sure it really does what you intend.

Comment: I didn't even saw the syntax errors, just got distracted by the tables to create a menu, i thought a row of td's always had the same height, so the slideUp effect would have no result.

Comment: @Han Dijk But you're right. This approach is fundamentally wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

You are going wrong with using tables for a list.
Use a list containing list-items.

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="http://..."></a></li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="http://..."></a></li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="http://..."></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

and float the list items left

```
ul li.menu_item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Your animation should work now, also you could use the jquery hover function

```
$(".menu_item").hover(over, out);
```

to make it a little easier

Comment: IMHO float-left is a widely accepted method to float things left, i use it at least once on every site i build, no problems. You could  also use display: inline-block;, but this will give tou some whitespace issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete code in this page:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdfj8/1/

The problem was the `method` and `callback` arguments.

Regards.